# Set HTML Form Input To JS Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read user input into a form back to them, sort of a confirmation before they send it in. I have some text elements on the page with their corresponding IDs. I would think that I just need to set the variables equal to the values of the input field, but when the function runs it just returns blank.

I have a function that sets the variables to the `.value` of that form input, but where I might be getting hung up is that there is no default value on the input field, I would think that the value is set after the user inputs something.

Example user inputs "John Doe" into field shouldn't that change the value of that field to "John Doe"?

```
var Phone;

document.getElementById('confirm-details').onclick = ConfirmDetails()

function ConfirmDetails() {
    // Set variable to form input
    Phone = document.getElementById("InputPhone").value;
    // Change text element to variable
    document.getElementById("BookingPhone").innerHTML = Phone;
};
```

Maybe I'm just confused about the `.value` attribute but I thought that the value on an input field should be what the user inputted.

Comment: Yes, `value` attribute reflects the text user enters to the input element. But, `value` as well as `innerHTML` are values, they will not change automatically. That means that the content of `#BookingPhone` changes only when you're actually clicking on the input element. (After you've fixed the code according to what Imaguest has answered.) Probably you want to use `input` (for realtime copying) or `change` (after finished entering) event instead of `click` here.

Answer (score 1):

This row

```
document.getElementById('confirm-details').onclick = ConfirmDetails()
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('confirm-details').onclick = ConfirmDetails
```

You don't want that `document.getElementById('confirm-details').onclick` references the result of the function `ConfirmDetails` (here void) but the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .value, you need to be using .innerText

```
Phone = document.getElementById("InputPhone").innerText;
```

Comment: Nope, [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Technical_summary) is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element), and can't contain HTML, it does not have `innerText` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
object.oninput = function(){
    ConfirmDetails();
};
```

or, shorthand:

```
object.oninput = function(){ConfirmDetails()};
```

You should also use `document.getElementById().innerHTML()` to get the text

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me. I appreciate all the answers!

```
<script>
document.getElementById("confirm-details").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("BookingName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("InputName").value;
document.getElementById("BookingEmail").innerHTML = document.getElementById("InputEmail").value;
document.getElementById("BookingPhone").innerHTML = document.getElementById("InputPhone").value;
document.getElementById("InputDay").innerHTML = document.getElementById("BookingDay").value;
document.getElementById("InputTime").innerHTML = document.getElementById("BookingTime").value;
document.getElementById("InputService").innerHTML = document.getElementById("BookingService").value;
document.getElementById("InputExtra").innerHTML = document.getElementById("BookingExtra").value;
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe you are trying to accomplish:

```js
function confirmDetails() {
    // Set variable to form input
    var phone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;
    
    var confirmMsg = 'is ' + phone + ' correct?' + '<br> <input type="button"  value="Yes" onclick="confirmed()"> ';
    // Change text element to variable
    document.getElementById("bookingPhone").innerHTML = confirmMsg;
};

function confirmed(){
alert('confirmed');

}
```

```html
<input id="inputPhone" type="text" placeholder="input here">
<input type="button" onclick="confirmDetails()" value="Submit">
<br>
<span id="bookingPhone"></span>
```

When the button is clicked, it runs the function `confirmDetails` and sets the variable `phone` to the user's input. I set variable `confirmMsg` to the confirm message which reads back the user's input. I used a span with a unique ID and sent the variable `confirmMsg` to it.

I put the confirm message into a variable to make it more versatile, should you need it elsewhere.